# What is the difference between a JS object using literal notation and a namespace

Tags: javascript

I'm taking an online class on Javascript and can't seem to find any separation between a namespace and an object without a constructor function.

For example, below is the book's example for a namesapce

```
var MyNamespace = {
    myFunction1: function(someParameters) {
        // Implementation code…
    },
    myFunction2: function(someParameters) {
        // Implementation code…
    },
    message: "Hello World",
    count: 42
}
```

Then, using object literal notation here is the example for an object

```
var objectName = { 
    property1: value1, 
    property2: value2,  

};
```

Syntactically they look almost exactly the same. Both are declared using the `var` keyword and, generally, intended to be scoped globally. Both also define members publicly. The object example uses a line delimiter but... not sure that matters too much.

The properties are also accessed the same using dot notation:

```
MyNamespace.myFunction1
objectName.property1
```

They can also share the same public property names. For example, the example below give the appropriate values for `.property1` for both the namespace and the object.

```
    var MyNamespace = {
        property1: "nsValue" 
    }
    var objectName = { 
        property1: "objValue" 
    };
    console.log(MyNamespace.property1);
    console.log(objectName.property1);
```

While there's a (good) chance I'm missing something it seems for all intents and purposes there is no difference between a JavaScript namespace and an object created using object literal notation. What am I missing?

Comment: They are both object literals, and are the same, someone just decided to give the first one a fancier name I think ?

Comment: Yeah, there's no difference here.  Perhaps further along in the book they may transform one of them into a function based object, along with local scope etc.  Keep reading!

Comment: There is no namespacing in JavaScript. The technique the book demonstrates is just using single global object to hold variables that would otherwise be global.

Comment: Objects are *used* as namespaces, just like they are used as lookup tables, records, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "namespace" is just a grouping of objects and functions.  An object literal can be used to implement a Namespace.  Conventionally, when an object is used in this way, you'll capitalize the first letter just the same as you would a function constructor (as you have done here with MyNamespace).  If your app requires use of global scope, it's good practice to use a namespace like this to prevent name conflicts (just as jQuery uses $ as a namespace in order to access all the methods and properties of its API).

Answer (score 2):

Object literal is one of the ways of achieving the concept of namespacing in JavaScript. I believe that when you talk about namespacing, you are referring to the concept of avoiding collisions with other objects and variables. However, namespacing can be achieved using other patterns as well like using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Execution). One of the most frequent examples of namespacing is when you are working with jQuery. Usually to prevent conflicting uses of the `$` variable, it is recommended that you pass in the `jQuery` variable to the anonymous function and then assign it to the `$` variable.

```
(function ( $ ) {

    var shade = "#556b2f";

    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", shade );
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

This basically ensures that the `$` variable will always be assigned to the `jQuery` object within that function.